# When creating a Windows Installer, is it possible to add othere .msi or .exe dependencies?

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I would like to install [Sox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/14.4.2/) along with my WPF application and add Sox to the clients PATH variable. Sox doesn't provide an `.msm` module that I can merge into my installer so I was wondering if there was a way to load external `.msi` or `.exe` installers before installing my own application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Most installer authoring tools out there can generate a [bootstrapper](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bootstrapper%20installer) for your installer.

This is practically an EXE wrapper around your installer (if your installer is an MSI) which executes custom code before launching the installation of your MSI, such as launching one or more multiple installations of dependency applications required by your own app.